# How to incorporate gradient fill in embedded files in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, embed

1. I've placed File B (a circle with a gradient fill) inside File A (simple blue background).
2. When I embed File B the gradient is not treated as a regular fill - instead it gets a weird double mask around it (see attached)

Is there a way to embed and expand a file with a gradient inside of it in such a way that the gradient is preserved as a regular fill?[image]

Comment: What versions of Illustrator? Why embedding rather than copy/pasting? Your gradient is being rasterized (that's why there's a mask) you need to first determine why the gradient is not holding up.

Comment: Illustrator CC, I will be doing this for multiple files and really need to embed external files to optimize my workflow.

Comment: Hmm.. it would appear to be a limitation of the embedded file. It's actually not rasterized, it's a rectangle with a circle clipping mask (when I set it up). I think this is actually one to ask over at the Adobe Forums -> http://forums.adobe.com/community/illustrator <- since it's far more tech support than actual design.

Comment: We could probably answer this better if we understood your goal. Why embed a gradient, when a linked file would be more flexible. Why not use an Illustrator gradient?
That being said, you usually see this effect when you try opening a pdf file in Illustrator. The gradient gets masked-out. - You can try releasing the Clipping Mask on the object (Command + Alt + 7), but I'm not sure that's really what you're looking for.